# Are cron tasks in `/etc/cron.d/` files supposed to not contain `sudo`?

Tags: sudo, cron

In `/etc/cron.d/myjob`, I create a cron task of running a bash script and redirect its stdout and stderr to a log file. The script contains a line of `sudo` running a command.

In the log file:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Does that cause some problem that needs my attention?

I was wondering if cron tasks in `/etc/cron.d/` files are supposed to not contain `sudo`?

Thanks.

Comment: The script contains sudo. The script is supposed to run both with and without cron. I am not supposed to modify the script just for running it with cron and /etc/cron.d/myjob

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Supposed" is a judgement call.

Commands called from `/etc/cron.d/` are run as a specified user (either `root` or any other one; it's defined in the cron line).  So, normally, there's no need for `sudo`.

However if you *do* have a script that calls `sudo` then you need to make sure the `sudoers` entry is correct.  In particular:

- Make sure the entry is assigned to the user running the script (this may be `root`)
- Make sure the entry has the `NOPASSWD` attribute set so it can run without anyone needing to enter a password.

The error you're seeing is because the `sudo` command need a password, but there's no terminal to provide it.

A well written script would detect if it was running with the right permissions and not call `sudo` at all, but there's a lot of bad scripts :-)

Comment: Thanks. (1) I was wondering what "the sudoers entry" is? In /etc/sudoers, do you mean add an entry for the script? If the script can be run by any one (root or not), how can I specify that in the entry?  (2) Does the sudo error  means that sudo command failed?  (3) In the cron job line in the crontab file, I specify a nonroot user in the user field,  and a shell script which contains sudo for superuser privilleges. So what shall I do instead?

Comment: For (3), there is an example here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478897/does-cron-modify-execution-environment-and-make-tor-servce-not-change-exit-node

Comment: (4) "A well written script would detect if it was running with the right permissions and not call sudo at all, but there's a lot of bad scripts" https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479055/shell-script-use-sudo-inside-it-vs-run-it-with-sudo#479055